# JPQL Query not valid. Error about unable to create object appears upon executing query

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I am trying to convert a SQL query to JQL, and though my code compiles, when the query is executed an error about it being unable to create object of the type I want appears.

```
SELECT js
FROM TableObject js
WHERE js
IN (
    SELECT jsa 
    FROM TableObject jsa 
    JOIN TableObject jsb 
    ON (
        jsa.job = jsb.job 
        AND jsa.key='power'
        AND jsa.value=:keyValue1 
        AND jsb.key = 'defense'
        AND jsb.settingValue=:keyValue2)) 
        AND js.job IN (
            SELECT j from OtherTableObject j where j.type = :type
        ) ORDER BY js.createDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL doesn't have an 'ON' operator. what you probably want is something like:

```
SELECT js
FROM TableObject js
WHERE js
IN (
    SELECT jsa 
    FROM TableObject jsa 
    JOIN TableObject jsb 
    WHERE (
        jsa.job = jsb.job 
        AND jsa.key='power'
        AND jsa.value=:keyValue1 
        AND jsb.key = 'defense'
        AND jsb.settingValue=:keyValue2
    )
) AND js.job IN (
    SELECT j 
    from OtherTableObject j
    where j.type = :type
)
ORDER BY js.createDate DESC
```